# How to embed a .zip file for downloading in an html document?

Tags: html

I have a simple html document locally on my computer that looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<h3>
    Python Script that partially automates sending my work hours to my boss. 
</h3>
<a href="automate_emails.zip">download</a>
</html>
```

In the folder containing this file, I have the automate_emails.zip. When I open this html locally on my computer clicking download works as expected- the .zip downloads. However, when I email the html document to myself, the download no longer works (I think?) because I am now opening the html document from the cloud where it no longer has access to the automate_emails.zip.

How do I fix this so the webpage will have access to the .zip file even when it is not opened locally? Do I need a hosting service for this?

Comment: `Do I need a hosting service for this?` Yes

Answer (score 0):

To solve your issue, you should host it somewhere. You can use Google Drive, Onedrive or similar platforms for that and have necessary permissions to access. After hosting it, you can update the ***href*** value as the url of the file. It will work fine.

Answer (score -1):

You obviously need to host upload that document somewehere online.

The easiest way would be to host the website and upload the .zip file as well.